# How to move Parent page to Details page in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic3

Hi beginner for ionic apps development and in my application in my Dashboard screen i have side menu functionality as like my below image,But when i want to move Dashboard page to Details Page Dashboard Navigation bar is appear in Details Page how can i resolve this problem can some one help me please

### DashBoard.ts:

```
export class SettingsPage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

 moveToNextPage(){
    this.navCtrl.push(DetailsPage);
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving with using rootNav.

```
import { App } from "ionic-angular";

constructor(
    private app: App
)

moveToNextPage(){
    const nav = this.app.getRootNav();
    nav.push(DetailsPage);
}
```